# option selector based on text

Tags: jquery

Everywhere on SO there is only selector via `value`, but I want to select `option` based on it text.

For example, I have this:

```
<select id="some-id">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select>
```

How get option with text equal to "2"? Something like this:

```
jQuery("#some-id option[text='2']")
```

But it is not working for me, how it should be done?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5941874/select-option-by-text-using-jquery

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744289/jquery-how-to-select-an-option-by-its-text

Comment: You have accepted a wrong answer. Read the comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should probably work:

```
$("#some-id option").filter(function() { return $(this).text() == '2'; });
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`:contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector:

```
var option = jQuery("#some-id option:contains('2')");
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/eNzuf/).

Comment: But it will also return those options where the value is 122, no?

Comment: @Cupidvogel - It will indeed. Sorry, didn't read your question carefully enough. The `filter` method in another answer will do the trick nicely.

Comment: For my purpose it would be corrent answer anyway ;)